# LZW decoding miss the first code entry

Tags: java, lzw

I followed the  [Rosetta Java code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#Java) implementation.

I tried do this LZW coding with my own Dictionary and not with the ASCII Dictionary which was used.
When I try with my own Dictioanry there is a problem about decoding... The result is wrong, because each of decoded word don't view the first `'a'` letter.
The result have to be `'abraca abrac abra'` and not `'braca brac bra'`

I see the problem in decode() method at `String act = "" + (char)(int)compressed.remove(0);` This will remove all first 'a' letter.
But I don't have any ideas how can I modify this line... 
For example if I use the `String act = "";`instead of above line... the coding will be very wrong, or use another command... I don't know how can I solve this little problem... Or maybe I am looking for on the bad way for the solution.

```
public class LZW {  


public static List<Integer> encode(String uncompressed) {

    Map<String,Integer> dictionary = DictionaryInitStringInt();        
    int dictSize = dictionary.size();

    String act = "";
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (char c : uncompressed.toCharArray()) {
        String next = act + c;
        if (dictionary.containsKey(next))
            act = next;
        else {
            result.add(dictionary.get(act));
            // Add next to the dictionary.
            dictionary.put(next, dictSize++);
            act = "" + c;
        }
    }

    // Output the code for act.
    if (!act.equals(""))
        result.add(dictionary.get(act));
    return result;
} 

public static String decode(List<Integer> compressed) {

    Map<Integer,String> dictionary = DictionaryInitIntString();        
    int dictSize = dictionary.size();

    String act = "" + (char)(int)compressed.remove(0);
    //String act = "";
    String result = act;

    for (int k : compressed) {            
        String entry;
        if (dictionary.containsKey(k))
            entry = dictionary.get(k);
        else if (k == dictSize)
            entry = act + act.charAt(0);
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Nincs ilyen kulcs: " + k);

        result += entry;

        dictionary.put(dictSize++, act + entry.charAt(0));

        act = entry;
    }
    return result;
}

public static Map<String,Integer> DictionaryInitStringInt()
{               
    char[] characters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j', 'k','l','m','n',
                    'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ','!',
                    '?','.',','};
    int charactersLength = characters.length;

    Map<String,Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < charactersLength; i++)
            dictionary.put("" + characters[i], i); 

    return dictionary;
}

public static Map<Integer,String> DictionaryInitIntString()
{               
    char[] characters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j', 'k','l','m','n',
                    'o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',' ','!',
                    '?','.',','};
    int charactersLength = characters.length;

    Map<Integer,String> dictionary = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < charactersLength; i++)
            dictionary.put(i,"" + characters[i]); 

    return dictionary;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> compressed = encode("abraca abrac abra");
    System.out.println(compressed);

    String decodeed = decode(compressed);
    // decodeed will be 'braca brac bra'
    System.out.println(decodeed);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rosetta example use

```
"" + (char) (int) compressed.remove(0);
```

because the first 256 entries of the dictionnary map exactly the 'char' values.

With a custom dictionnary this line should be:

```
String act = dictionary.get(compressed.remove(0));
```